# Selecting one row from sqlite database using rawQuery and rowid in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, rowid

I've created an external SQLite database that looks something like this: [image: image of a few rows of a database]

What I want to do in my Android application is to load all the values from one row using ROWID and put them into array. For example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Dairy WHERE ROWID = 1", null);
```

This would return all the values from row 1: 51, 35, 63. However, this always returns just first value, in this case 51. Also, the `cursor.getCount()` always returns 1.

Here's my complete code:

```
db = getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Dairy WHERE ROWID = 1", null);

yData = new int[cursor.getCount()];

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        yData[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
db.close();
```

Comment: Why do you cycle through the returned rows, if it's only one? `cursor.getCount() always returns 1` . Which is **correct**! You only returned 1 row. Maybe you're confusing between rows and columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I correctly understand you need to return value of  every column from the single row. Since you select only single row and want to get value from every column you need only to get the  index of every column. and next iterate through them. Here is the code how it can be done.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Dairy WHERE ROWID = 1 Limit 1", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
    yData = new int[columnNames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        // Assume every column is int
        yData[i] = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnNames[i]));
    }  
}

cursor.close();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getInt (int columnIndex)` method returns the requested column and not the entire row. Whereas, `moveToFirst ()` and `moveToNext ()` will move the cursor to the first or next row if the cursor is not empty or if the cursor is not past the last row if `moveToNext ()` is called. Otherwise both will return false.

So, on success, a cursor contains a complete row, and you can access the elements either by provide 0 based indices directly or getting a column index by `getColumnIndex(String columnName)` providing a column name to get the index of that column and accessing that column then.

You can refer to the android developers guide, [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

Answer (score 0):

You always get the same value:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        //cursor.getInt(0); You probably want to get 0, 1 & 2
        yData[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: This seems to repeat OP's mistake -- `cursor.getCount()` iterates rows, not columns as intended.